# Get Accesstoken Token Error in Box Oauth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

please help to Get accesstoken after get code i am request to get accesstoken through following code in C# but it always return me The remote serve (400) bad request

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={your_code}&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}' \
-X POST
```

Here is the code I'm using :

```
Stream stream = null; 
WebRequest webRequest = null; 
StreamReader streamReader = null; 
WebResponse webResponse = null; 
webRequest = WebRequest.Create("box.com/api/oauth2/token"); 

webRequest.Method = "POST"; 
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("'grant_type=authorization_code&code={myc??ode}&client_id={myclient_id}&client_secret={myclient_secret}'"); 
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length; 

Stream reqstr = webRequest.GetRequestStream();

reqstr.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
reqstr.Close();

webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream(); 
streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);

WebResponseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Stream stream = null;
WebRequest webRequest = null;
StreamReader streamReader = null;
WebResponse webResponse = null;


webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token");
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Comment: byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("'grant_type=authorization_code&code={mycode}&client_id={myclient_id}&client_secret={myclient_secret}'");
webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
]
Stream reqstr = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
reqstr.Close();
webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
WebResponseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();